# Spring Security config cannot detected HttpSecurity package

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I noticed that WebSecurityConfigurAdapter is no longer used in the latest version of spring boot.

So I decided to modify only my security config file in the latest way first. (However, I still beat the old version of spring boot.)

I referred to the link post below.

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

The following is the spring boot version that I am using, pom.xml file information, error message, spring security config file information.

spring boot version : 2.1.7.RELEASE

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>myid</groupId>
    <artifactId>operator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myname</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## security config java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  {

    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**/ajax/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/login/process").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login/process")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .failureUrl("/login?session=fail")
        .and()
            .logout()
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .and()
            .httpBasic();
        
        http.sessionManagement()
            .invalidSessionUrl("/login?session=timeout")
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
            .expiredUrl("/login?session=dupli");
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
}
```

Error Message

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.7.RELEASE)

2023-06-19 10:35:51.705  INFO 30636 --- [  restartedMain] d.s.operator.MyApplication  : Starting MyApplication on DESKTOP-HQRQ2MM with PID 30636 (C:\MyRoot)
2023-06-19 10:35:51.705  INFO 30636 --- [  restartedMain] d.s.operator.MyApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-06-19 10:35:51.920  INFO 30636 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-19 10:35:51.920  INFO 30636 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-19 10:35:51.920  INFO 30636 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2023-06-19 10:35:51.933  INFO 30636 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-11].[localhost].[/]    : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-19 10:35:51.933  INFO 30636 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 227 ms
2023-06-19 10:35:51.967  INFO 30636 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@e5df6ae, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@15c87050, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1a56a7fa, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6e41513f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@11bdfbc1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@435db674, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@47a14995, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@12e23a70, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2fe4fd, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@39ad9645, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@166b9ffd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3ca2d04e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@71641fea, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5e52581, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3d9436fb]
2023-06-19 10:35:51.969  WARN 30636 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [myRoot/SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChain' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2023-06-19 10:35:51.969  INFO 30636 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-19 10:35:51.973  INFO 30636 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-19 10:35:52.054 ERROR 30636 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method filterChain in dg.smtpl.operator.security.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.
```

For your information, adding component scan annotations to the main method as shown below does not result in an error message.
But I want to correct the error in the config instead of adding it to the main class. Is there a way?

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders"})
public class DgSmtplOperatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DgSmtplOperatorApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ofcourse that won't work, that is for Spring Security versions supplied with Spring Boot 2.6 and up, older versions don't apply.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your answer. I didn't care about the relationship of dependencies for each version. I reviewed the version-specific support in the official document again and it worked fine after modifying the version information as below!
Spring boot -> 2.7.12 , mybatis -> 2.3.1